# convert "[ ]" to null in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying jquery with ajax call....

here is the code..

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/turnover/GetTurnover' + repType,//?packageID=' + packageID,
    data: { "packageID": packageID },
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    success: function myfunction(response) {}
});
```

here in response the data i am receiving initially on page load is " [ ] "
now i want to convert it into "null" value... please help with this.... thank you....

[image]

Comment: you should send proper response from you backend, best way a json string in your case and then parse it

Comment: `[ ]` means an empty array or is it just a string?

Comment: in controller the json returning " data " is of type list. on page load the data is empty and the response in View value is " [ ]  ".....

Comment: @htiru Kindly check my answer and tell if that works for you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar it doesn't work...... please have a look into the image..

Comment: @htiru `response` is an object and its length is 0. So it should really go inside the `if` condition. After the `response = null` try using `console.log(response)` and you must get `null`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it doesn't work still.....

Comment: @htiru What exactly do you want?

Comment: @PraveenKumar .  I want the value length as "0"... As I want to display an error message when length is "0"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99505/discussion-between-htiru-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` function, you can do this:

```
// make the function anonymous by removing `myfunction`
success: function (response) {
  if (response == "[]" || (typeof response == "object" && response.length == 0))
    response = null;
}
```